# How to pass Renderpartial view in _Layout page

Tags: model-view-controller

Here i create a partial view when i try to implement in _Layout page its throughing an Error as cant convert void to object

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li>@Html.RenderPartial("_AutoCompltetext")</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li>
@{
Html.REnderPartial("_Autocomplte")
}
</li>
```